TL494 step-down converter with CC/CV
I want to build a universal charger for Li-Ion, LiFePo4, VRLA-AGM, and similar batteries (or just a power supply with CC/CV). I'll designate in advance that the maximum output voltage of the converter is 3-35 V, and the current is 40 A (the converter is only step-down, the maximum voltage is limited to either 35 V or VIN — losses on components).  The input voltage is accordingly 5-40 V (if I need to charge only 1S Li-ion, I will be satisfied with 5 V at the input).
However, I'm thinking about controlling the feedback of TL494 by some DAC (like AD5680)... The controller is an ESP32 with different charge profiles.  The INA228 will measure current/voltage. I do not understand how to correctly set for example CC = 500 mA, and after CC = 40 A, because the difference is huge, not understanding what voltage to set on the error amplifiers TL494. Let's not consider the power part of the converter, just assume that I have in place components that will withstand 1.5 kilowatts of power.

what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

@jsotola Sorry, I told everything but not on the case) The question is in the organization of feedback - how to make accurate regulation of current and voltage

Use a cascaded current-mode control, both to ease compensation, and to set the current limit:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Current error amp can be one of the internal error amps of the TL494; the other can be used for temperature or fault purposes, say, but mostly doesn't matter and can be disabled when not needed.
Mind that TL494's modulator is inverting, so the error amp polarity is probably backwards here, or the driver must be inverting.  You can resolve it either way.
VSET and ILIM can simply be driven by DAC outputs.
This works best in average current mode control, for which L1 will be relatively large (giving current ripple below say 20% at full output), and for which a powdered iron core will suffice.  C1 does not need special ESR or anything -- this is one of the advantages of current-mode control.  Both loops can be compensated independently, and the current loop's dominant pole can be above the LC filter double-pole (another advantage -- not that this responsiveness is exactly required for something as slow as a battery charger).
The clamp circuit is shown mostly for representation:

Note that, as shown, U4 can't pull ISET down more than a diode drop above GND, so either U4 should have bipolar supplies, or the IFB signal should be biased a volt or two above GND for single-supply use.
When inactive (voltage loop controlling), U4's output saturates to VCC.  After ISET rises above ILIM, it takes some time to recover and clamp accurately, determined by the voltage swing and slew rate.  Alternative connections may be worth considering.

If a fixed current limit is acceptable, then U3's supply voltage (or divided down by Rvs and another resistor from ISET to GND) can be used to set the limit without needing U4.

Thanks for the detailed response. A lot to think about :)
