Designing CCCV supply
This is a pretty broad question, but my knowledge go as far as constant voltage supplys design (not even SMPS). I'm doing some research to learn how to design an SMPS for charging batteries, but I can't understand how to make a constant current supply with the SMPS, rather, the better way to design a constant current supply. The output power to be achieved is between 300-600W.

Will it be better to design an SMPS that can work as CV and CC? Or should I make a common SMPS circuit pretty well tested, and add to the output a constant current circuit?
If it's better to design a circuit exclusively for constant current, what type of circuit should I use for 600W?
I know how to use µC, when designing the SMPS, should I use the µC for controlling the PWM signal and as a consequence, vary the output power of the SMPS?


Usually, you design for constant voltage and an extra loop for CC is added. This is what is done for traditional chargers with a flyback structure. That being said, for this level of power, some topologies do not like to see a variable output voltage (when the battery is low for instance) like the LLC if the range is too wide. You can have a look at this project in which we used a micro to control a LLC converter.

You may find this of interest: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/718765/tl494-step-down-converter-with-cc-cv/718770#718770

#1 depends, integrating CC up-front wil lower the BOM and simplify things, BUT it's also slower to do CC in "software" than say, an op amp. For a battery charger, a brief current spike usually won't hurt anything, so implementing a current limit in the control loop is fine. If it's for a sensitive million-dollar prototype, you want the limiting done in faster/more reliable hardware. #3, yeah, that's fine for a battery charger, they don't need to be very sensitive/fast, so you can do it all from the MCU. Do make sure it doesn't pass unlimited power until the MCU boots up.

Thanks for all the advices. I will be learning and add my final choice.
